# Passing a value to other sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a value in my sheet where I want to pass the value to other sheet using Google App Script, I have a simple code that can get the value but I don't know on how I can pass it to other sheet and create a new row in other sheet.

```
    function doit() {

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
    var FromSheet = ss.getSheetByName('s1');
    var ToSheet = ss.getSheetByName('s2');

    var firstname = fromsheet.getRange('A2');
    var lastname = fromsheet.getRange('B2');
    var data = firstname.getValue(); 
    var data1 = lastname.getValue();
    //To sheet code???

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify a bit the code and it i almost same code to paste value.

```
function doit() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
    var FromSheet = ss.getSheetByName('s1');
    var ToSheet = ss.getSheetByName('s2');

    var firstname = fromsheet.getRange('A2').getValue();
    var lastname = fromsheet.getRange('B2').getValue();
    //Copy to others sheet
    ToSheet.getRange('A2').setValue(firstname);
    ToSheet.getRange('A2').setValue(firstname);
}
```

You can also copy the data with copyValuesToRange() 
see : https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyvaluestorangegridid-column-columnend-row-rowend
code example from site :

```
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var FromSheet = ss.getSheetByName('s1');
 var ToSheet = ss.getSheetByName('s2');
 var range = FromSheet.getRange("A2:B2");
 range.copyTo(ToSheet.getRange("A2"), {contentsOnly:true});
```

Stéphane

Comment: Hi  stephane, i try to run the code but it give me an error Q.: TypeError: Cannot call method "getRange" of null.? and why only A2 in range.copyTo(ToSheet.getRange("A2") ? if i also copy up to B2? just asking noob here :)

Comment: code must be run in a spreadsheet which contain sheets names s1 and s2. A2:B2 means we select both cell directly and not one by one.

Comment: Ya, i also see this post  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4211504/typeerror-cannot-call-method-getrange-of-null-line-0 Btw thanks again steph :)

Comment: Btw Step, can i directly use getRange(2, 9, 3, 5);? this will copy range of Row 2 and to the Column 9 and also the Row 3 to Column 5? get all of the value of that column and row.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a couple errors in it:

```
function doit() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() // missing ;
var FromSheet = ss.getSheetByName('s1');
var ToSheet = ss.getSheetByName('s2');

var firstname = fromsheet.getRange('A2'); // fromsheet must be FromSheet (Caps Matter)
var lastname = fromsheet.getRange('B2'); // same here
var data = firstname.getValue(); 
var data1 = lastname.getValue();
//To sheet code???

}
```

Here's what I would do:

```
function doit() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var FromSheet = ss.getSheetByName('s1');
var ToSheet = ss.getSheetByName('s2');
var firstname = FromSheet.getRange('A2').getValue(); // simplify lines
var lastname = FromSheet.getRange('B2').getValue(); // simplify lines

ToSheet.getRange("CELL TO PUT FIRSTNAME").setValue(firstname);
ToSheet.getRange("CELL TO PUT LASTNAME").setValue(lastname);
}
```