# Google App Maker returns "Cannot call method getRange of null" when calling createGroup()

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-app-maker

I need to create interface through Google App Maker, the interface basically will read the data which is information of my Google groups from spreadsheet and create the groups. There is only a button and whenever button is clicked the createGroup() method is called to run. However, I am getting the error when I preview the app;

> TypeError: Cannot call method "getRange" of null. at createGroup (Server:16)

As my understanding, it says the spreadsheet empty but it is not.

My client and server code like below;

Server:

```
function createGroup() {
  var sheetID = 'ID';
  var spreadsheetName= 'Name';

  var spreadsheetId = sheetID;
  var sheetName= spreadsheetName;

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId);
  //var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  **var Avals = sheet.getRange("B1:B").getValues();**
  var Alast = Avals.filter(String).length;

  for (var j = 2; j< Alast+1; j++) {
      var columnEmailName = sheet.getRange(j,2).getValue()+"@domainname.com"; //Group's email
      var columnGroupName = sheet.getRange(j,2).getValue(); //Group's name

      try {
          groups= AdminDirectory.Groups.get(columnEmailName);
      }
      catch(e){
          var response = AdminDirectory.Groups.insert({
              "name": columnGroupName, 
              "email": columnEmailName, 
              "description": "This is the "+ columnGroupName+ " group."
          });
      }
  }
}
```

Client:

```
function createGroup() {
  google.script.run
    .withFailureHandler(function(error) {
      console.error(error);
    })
    .withSuccessHandler(function() {

    })
    .createGroup();
}
```

Could you please help if anyone knows about the error?

Comment: Why didn't you read the documentation for the `getSheetByName` method? It will return `null` if that name doesn't match a sheet. If you swear that sheet exists, make sure you do something debugging - for example, call `getSheets()` and log the names of every sheet in that array. Verify you're working with the correct Spreadsheet. And so on.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: Cannot call method "getRange" of null. (line 0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4211504/typeerror-cannot-call-method-getrange-of-null-line-0)